# Create a folder based on user input vbscript

Tags: vbscript, inputbox

Sorry very new to all of this. I am currently trying to put together a basic script to create a folder based on use input. I can get to the point where the input can be done and the folder is created but not with inputbox data.

```
dim UserName

UserName = InputBox ("Please enter user name")

if Username = "" then
MsgBox("No username entered")

do while(UserName = "")
UserName = InputBox ("Please enter user name")
    if Username = "" then
    MsgBox("No Username entered")
    else
    MsgBox("Please click OK to continue")
    end if
Loop

else
MsgBox ("Please click ok to continue")

end if

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run "cmd /c mkdir c:\temp\UserName"
```

As I said am very new to this so am open to any tips or pointers in the right direction.

Cheers in advance

Comment: Use the Scripting.FileSystemObject interface "CreateFolder" method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why people make everything so complicated. A very simple script is here:

```
*strfolder = InputBox("Please enter a name for your new folder:")
set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.CreateFolder "c:\" & strfolder*
```

Answer (score 0):

To get it to work, all you have to do is change the last line to this:

```
objShell.Run "cmd /c mkdir c:\temp\" & UserName
```

This way you use the value of `UserName` instead of the word UserName.

By way of tips...

Your flow is a bit redundant, you can do the same thing by updating your loop. Here is one possible route:

```
dim UserName
Do
   UserName = InputBox ("Please enter user name")
   If UserName = "" then
      Msgbox "No Username entered"
   end if
Loop Until UserName <> ""

MsgBox "Please click OK to continue"

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run "cmd /c mkdir c:\temp\" & UserName
```

Also it may be better to just end the script if `UserName = ""` because `""` is the return value of InputBox if cancel is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for your help Daniel, will take suggestions on board.